# Registration with PDO/PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a problem through build a registration system. I don't know where is the problem, because I'm a beginner in PHP OOP.

Here's my registration class:

```
<?php
/*
 *=======================
 * REGISTRATION CLASS !!!
 * ======================
 */
include_once '/../core/registration.php';
include_once '/../core/db_connect.php';

class registration {

private $db;

function __construct() {                 /* Connecting with MySQL */
    $this->db = new db_connect();
    $this->db = $this->db->connect();
}                                         /* End of connection */

function registration($username, $password1, $password2, $email, $date) {
    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password1) && !empty($password2) && !empty($email))      {

        $q = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, date, logged, admin) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $q->bindParam(1, $username);
        $q->bindParam(2, $password1);
        $q->bindParam(3, $email);
        $q->bindParam(4, $date);
        $q->bindParam(5, '0');
        $q->bindParam(6, '0');
        $q->execute();

    }
}

}
?>
```

Here is a file, that is running, when user clicks on 'register' button:

```
<?php
include_once '/../classes/registration.php';

if(isset($_POST['regUser'])) {

$username = $_POST['regUsername'];
$pass1 = $_POST['regPassword1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['regPassword2'];
$email = $_POST['regEmail'];
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$obj = new registration();
$obj->registration($username, $password1, $password2, $email, $date);

}
?>
```

For safety, I'll put also a connection file:

```
<?php
class db_connect {

function connect() {
    return new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=oop", "root", "");
}

}
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Any error message?

Comment: If you find yourself writing the words "doesn't work", hit yourself with a small cudgel, delete what you wrote, and replace it with: (1) what you were expecting, and (2) what actually happened. And remember that a supernatural being (of no particular religious denomination) kills a cute and furry creature every time someone on Stack Overflow uses "it doesn't work" as a bug report.

Comment: Maybe he is a member of a secret, old and obscure organisation and this is what he want: kills a cute and furry creature! :D

Comment: I haven't got any error message.

Comment: Also, beware of the SQL injection (even with bindParam). You should specify a type (eg. PDO::PARAM_STR)

Comment: Did it, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one of the most common "error" with PDO.

With `bindParam`, you can only pass variables, not values.

In your registration() method, replace:

```
$q->bindParam(5, '0');
$q->bindParam(6, '0');
```

By:

```
$q->bindValue(5, '0');
$q->bindValue(6, '0');
```

With `bindValue` you can pass values and variables.

You can read the PHP manual for more info ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)).

Comment: Could you be more specific please? What happens? (normally the bindParam VS bindValue must solve your problem)

Comment: Nothig happens. I click on the 'register' button and then the code executes, but the data aren't send to the database.

Comment: Try to display `$q->execute()` error with: `if ($q->execute() != 0) { $errors = $q->errorInfo(); echo $errors[2]; }` (put that just after `$q->execute()`

Comment: Sorry, but I've maked a really big mistake. My action attribute was empty >.< Now, it's works perfect, but thnaks for your help ! THANKS !